# Load index.html when URL points to subfolder

Tags: html, apache, web-hosting

I'd like a URL that points to sub-folder to load index.html from that folder:

User types:

```
www.example.com/subpage/
```

Browser loads:

```
www.example.com/subpage/index.html
```

I'm using GoDaddy hosting and cPanel but their support said it's beyond their range of services to help me (!).

I tried adding .htaccess file to this sub-folder with this but it did not work:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

So far I have found that this works:

```
RedirectMatch ^/subfolder/?$ /subfolder/index.html
```

The problem is that the user is redirected and the "index.html" is visible in the address bar which is not ideal.

Any idea why DirectoryIndex wouldn't work?

Thank you

Comment: You need to implement a redirection or rewriting rule for cases where the requested URL points to the "folder". You can do that in dynamic configuration files (.htaccess), either inside the subfolder or in the root folder, but it is always better to place such rules in the real http servers host configuration. Not sure if a cheap hosting provider offers such option, though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a php rewrite rule in .htaccess that looked like this that was interfering with the default DorectoryIndex behavior.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$ 
RewriteRule . /rewrite.php [L]
```

Removing this fixed the problem! Yay!